# Debugging android app on device wont work

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having trouble debugging my android app on my phone. My Phone is an LG Optimus G running on android version 4.0.4. Everywhere says to update the driver, but when I do that, my computer doesn't recognize it. I have android ADT installed with SDK versions 4.2, 4.0.3, 2.3.3, and 2.2. I think it might be the fact that my phone is a 4.0.4 and not 4.0.3. And I have USB debugging enabled on my phone. The emulator is just to choppy and laggy to debug on. And one more thing, I have tried debugging already and it has not found the device, although i can find all of the files and pictures on File Explorer. Please help.

Comment: If you run `adb devices`, is your device listed there?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: I just ran it, and it isnt listed

Comment: I Just got everything working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows I suggest you try downloading PdaNet http://pdanet.co/, this app is used to share Internet from your android phone to your PC, BUT ALSO helps you install the correct drivers for your Android.

I've found that using this program is the most simple way to get most Android phones working on Windows, plus if you don't want the software you can just uninstall it and the drivers will be kept.